# Receber $index correcto após uso do filtro

Tags: angularjs

Olá,

Tenho uma galeria de imagens que contém uma caixa de pesquisa, basicamente quando o utilizador clica numa imagem abre uma lightbox com essa imagem.

Basicamente estou a passar o **$index** para uma função que abre o item nessa list com o index **$scope.list[lb.index]**

o código:

```
HTML
<input type="text" name="search" id="f_search" ng-model="query.name" />
<ul class="list" ng-show="list.length>0">
    <li ng-repeat="item in list | filter:query">
        <a class="img" ng-style="{'background-image':'url(/uploads/<%item.image%>)'}" ng-click="openLB($index)"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="lightbox" ng-if="lb.show">
    <a class="arrow" ng-show="list.length>1" ng-click="changeItemLB(lb.index, 'prev')">ANTERIOR</a>
    <a class="arrow" ng-show="list.length>1" ng-click="changeItemLB(lb.index, 'next')">PRÓXIMO</a>
    <div class="holder">
        <img ng-if="list[lb.index].image.length" ng-src="/uploads/<%list[lb.index].image%>" />
    </div>
</div>

Angular
$scope.openLB = function(index) {

    $scope.lb.show = true;
    $scope.lb.index = index;

};
$scope.changeItemLB = function(index, action) {

    var tot = $scope.list.length-1,
        goto = 0;

    if(action=='prev') goto = index==0 ? tot : index-1; 
    if(action=='next') goto = index==tot ? 0 : index+1; 

    $scope.openLB(goto);
}
```

O problema reside quando após a pesquisa o $index mantém-se o mesmo, o que faz com que seja aberta a imagem errada. Alguém sabe como dar a volta a isto?

Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Para utilizar a propriedade especial `$index` você tem que adicionar a expressão `track by $index` no final do `ngRepeat`:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in list | filter:query track by $index">
```